# bluemix iot platform dashboard access issue on firefox

Tags: firefox, ibm-cloud

I cannot access to the bluemix iot platform dashboard.
After clicking on launch dashboard firefox keeps spinning.
Used navigator is Firefox
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please try going to this website and logging in:  https://internetofthings.ibmcloud.com/#/
Once logged in, you can select your org from the drop down and you should see your dashboard.

I believe you are seeing the spinning wheel perhaps because you previously logged out and there is a known defect that shows spinning wheel yet doesn't redirect you to log in.  We expect the fix for this to be rolled out very soon.